# package javax.servlet does not exist eventhough tomcat lib\servlet-api.jar added in classpath env variable

Tags: java, windows, tomcat, servlets, classpath

Env details :

```
OS : Windows 7
Server : Apache Tomcat 7.x
```

I'm able to see `..\tomcat\path\lib\servlet-api.jar in path env variable` from command prompt but still, when i compile my servlet, I get following error

```
"package javax.servlet does not exist"
```

I've gone thru all previous questions and FYI, there is no trailing ; (semicolon)

one more important thing is, I'm able to compile it this way

```
javac -classpath ..\path\lib\servlet-api.jar MyFirstServlet.java
```

But

`javac MyFirstServlet.java` fails even though `..\path\lib\servlet-api.jar` is present in path env variable

Thanks in advance for your Suggestions

Comment: is this a typo javac MyFristServlet.java as in the earlier command you have  MyFirstServlet.java

Comment: `java` doesn't put the `path` env variable on the classpath.

Comment: Restarting the machine didn't help too

Comment: 1) add the file to classpath

Comment: Hi Sotirios

in that case, what is the work around

using javac -classpath ..\path\lib\servlet-api.jar NewServletAlways.java

would be painful, as i would be practicing 100's of servlets

Comment: yes Satya, it was a typo while posting the question

Comment: Thank you Satya and Sotirios, setting an env variable with name classpath=..\path\lib\servlet-api.jar solved the problem


But still, I'm interested in knowing how javac is working fine even though I set it in path env variable.. should it not fail, the same way its failing in case of servlet-api.jar class path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

setting an env variable with name classpath=..\path\lib\servlet-api.jar solved the problem But still, I'm interested in knowing how javac is working fine even though I set it in path env variable.. should it not fail, the same way its failing in case of servlet-api.jar class path?